# SOLR synonyms only on specific fields

Tags: solr

How can I configure SOLR to use synonyms ONLY on specific fields? I can't find anything in docs and I am using "SynonymGraphFilterFactory" in managed-schema.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr does this by default. Solr uses synonyms only in fields where the definition of the field references the `SynonymGraphFilterFactory` filter (notice that this can be directly defined on the field/field type or indirectly.)

For example, the default definition of the `text_general` references the `synonyms.txt` and so does the `text_en` but not `string` or `text_ca`.

If you have fields where you don't want synonyms to be applied you could create a new field definition similar to text_general and make sure it does **not** uses the synonyms filter.

For information about the `SynonymGraphFilterFactory` take a look at the [Filters section](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/about-filters.html) in the Solr guide. For information about how Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Filters work together take a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/master/tutorial.md#analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters).